# Jest ignore ReferenceError through eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, eslint

I'm fairly new to Node integration testing and I have a problem for which I need some help. I have to write test cases and I had setup the test environment and had written the first test case as well.

```
const request = require('supertest')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

test('test', () => {
    expect(1+1).toBe(2)
})
```

And when I try running the test using jest, I get the following error

**ReferenceError: Sample is not defined**

denoting to the below code.

```
const sampleSchema: new mongoose.Schema ({
///my schema goes in here
})

module.exports = Sample = mongoose.model('Sample', sampleSchema)
```

I rectified this and it showed another file and that kept going on. Also, changing the above also corrupts my program. I would like to know if it is possible to use eslint plugin to fix this issue(s). Please help!

Comment: If you simply remove `= Sample` from the export it should not have any reference errors

Comment: It so happens that if I remove this error, there is another error that appears in the same type but in a different file. That is why I'm looking to use eslint plugin (hopefully) to ignore all these errors and run my tests.